How to stop CMake setting "Character Set" in Visual Studio projects to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set"
I'm trying to convert my build to CMake and amongst other issues I have found that the generated project files set the Character Set value (in Advanced Settings) to Use Multi-Byte Character Set.
I want that to be set to Not Set.
I've tried adding remove_definitions("-D_MBCS") but that doesn't change that setting, OR remove the /D "_MBCS" option passed to the compiler.
How can I do this please (no I don't want Unicode set either).

I've been informed that:
CharacterSet is set as follows:
If the project adds a _UNICODE preprocessor definition, the CharacterSet is Unicode.
If the project adds a _SBCS  preprocessor definition, the CharacterSet is NotSet.
Otherwise, the CharacterSet is MultiByte.
so
target_compile_definitions(example PRIVATE _SBCS)
should do the job.
